# Automapper "ExplicitExpansion" not working when a constructor in parent DTO is declared

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am using the latest version of Automapper (12.0).

When applying a constructor on a parent DTO, "ExplicitExpansion" does not work.

Here My Model and DTOs:

```cs
class Maestro
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Alumno> Alumnos { get; set; }
    }

    class Alumno
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }
    }


    class MaestroDto
    {
        public MaestroDto(System.Guid id, string nombre, List<AlumnoDto> alumnos)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Alumnos = alumnos;
        }
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()]
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public List<AlumnoDto> Alumnos { get; set; }

    }

    class AlumnoDto
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }

    }
```

**Please note that `MaestroDto` has a constructor.**

This is my mapping configuration:

```cs
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
            {
                c.CreateMap<Maestro, MaestroDto>().ForMember(c => c.Alumnos, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());
                c.CreateMap<Alumno, AlumnoDto>();
            });

            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

When making projections with Automapper in this way:

```cs
List<MaestroDto> resultMaestro = mapper.ProjectTo<MaestroDto>(maestros.AsQueryable()).ToList();
```

**"Alumnos" is always loaded even when I have not specifically said I want it to be.**

**This is due to the constructor that has "MaestroDto", is this expected? I would expect that even having the constructor the property would be ignored if I wish, by not adding it in the query with the lambda expression.**

Here you can find the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vicabhu/7b57184eb72c96e4e0c2a5a227e6bc21).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cfg.DisableConstructorMapping()` or use `ConstructUsing` for this particular map.

Comment: You can also try `ForCtorParam` => `Ignore`.

Comment: Thank you `cfg.DisableConstructorMapping()` does the job

Answer (score 1):

Disabling mapping constructors solves the issue.

Adding `cfg.DisableConstructorMapping()` at the mapping initialization makes it work.